# The Land of Truth and Lies

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

You live in The Land of Truth and Lies, where any of your statements may be inverted in meaning, without prior warning. For example, if you intend to say "You're looking good today", you may magically (and quite unfortunately) say "It is not true that you're looking good today" instead. If you intend to say "You're looking horrible today", you may (also unfortunately) end up saying it without inversion.

How can you formulate every statement you make such that a compliment $c$ will get across clearly?

> Note that sub-statements when trying to say complex statements such as "The statement 'You are looking good today.' is true." may also be inverted. The previous statement might be delivered without inversions, or inverted to say any of the following:
>
> - "It is not true that the statement 'You are looking good today.' is true."
> - "The statement 'It is not true that you are looking good today.' is true."
> - "It is not true that the statement 'It is not true that you are looking good today.' is true."
>
> We also assume that compliments are non-paradoxical statements whose truth value can be determined immediately (i.e., you wouldn't go around saying "You will look good in 20 years" or "You dress up better than Steve, but Steve dresses up better than you").

Comment: How would "You look good and the sky is blue" be inverted?

Comment: All of your examples simply add "It is not true that". Are inversions always this formulaic, or can it also be inverted more like "You're looking horrible today" becomes "You're looking great today"?

Comment: Inversions can be anything as long as the meaning of the whole statement is flipped, but you don't need to rely on the specific phrase to come up with a solution.

Comment: "You look good and the sky is blue" could stay the same, become "You look bad and the sky is blue", become "You look good and the sky is not blue", or become "You look bad and the sky is not blue".

Comment: @Avi Does an insertion of any number of "nots" anywhere grammatically allowed in the sentence qualify as inversion? Can "you look good" be inverted to "someone other than you (not-you) looks good", in addition to "you look not good" and "you do not look good"?

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is not possible to accurately make this puzzle based on inverting meaning, because meaning is very difficult to specify with clarity. You can find the discussion that lead to this decision [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/conversation/how-can-you-invert-meaning).

Comment: Can we assume that all references to "meaning" and "say" apply only to words that come out of your mouth? That hand gestures or facial expressions are not inverted?

Answer (score 6):

> Use the fact that you can hear yourself speak while speaking:

> "My last statement is the truth. You look good. You look good. You look good. ... "
>  If the first statement is reverted, stop talking as soon as the last statement is reverted, else stop as soon as the last one comes out as intended.

> Although this may take infinite time, you can expect someone familiar with the rules of the land to get your meaning after two or more insults/compliments and cut you off with a thank you.

Comment: This technically works, but it could potentially require an infinite series of statements to clearly communicate the meaning. It's also not very nice to hear the wrong thing too many times. There exists a way to communicate a compliment with one statement (including 3 or less sub-statements).

Answer (score 4):

Start off by ignoring the fact that "sub-statements" can be inverted, and let's say that you want to say a true statement.  If your statement is non-self referential, then it is equivalent to one of "true" or "false" (⊤ or ⊥).  Obviously neither of these work; for example ⊤ could come out as ⊤ or ¬⊤ ⇔ ⊥.

So we need more.  If the statement is nontrivially self-referential, it is equivalent to either "this statement is true" or "this statement is false" (S or ¬S, letting S be the truth of the statement).  However neither of these work either; for example, S can come out as S or ¬S, and we have either S = S or S = ¬S, neither of which have a well-defined truth value.

So we need more!  Maybe we can let the statement depend on whether it was inverted?   The two nontrivial cases are "this statement is inverted" or "this statement is not inverted" (R or ¬R, letting R be whether the statement was inverted).  But now, R can come out as R (not inverted, so R = ⊥) or ¬R (inverted, so R = ⊤) and we get either ⊥ or ¬⊤ ⇔ ⊥, so the statement R is unambiguously ⊥.  Similarly, ¬R is unambiguously ⊤.

From here we can see that the key is that the meaning of our statement has to be negated when an inversion occurs, leading to the following solution:

> Let P be the statement "this statement was inverted an odd number of times", and C be the statement you want to say.  Then you should say P ⊕ C.
>
>  For example, "Either thou art more lovely than a summer's day or this statement was inverted an odd number of times."

There are eight cases to consider (note ⊥⊕Q ⇔ Q and ⊤⊕Q ⇔ ¬Q):

| P | C | ⋅⊕⋅ | Number of inversions | Statement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ⋅ | ⋅ | ⋅ | 0 (P=⊥) | P⊕C ⇔ ⊥⊕C ⇔ C |
| ¬ | ⋅ | ⋅ | 1 (P=⊤) | ¬P⊕C ⇔ ¬⊤⊕C ⇔ ⊥⊕C ⇔ C |
| ⋅ | ¬ | ⋅ | 1 (P=⊤) | P⊕¬C ⇔ ⊤⊕¬C ⇔ ¬¬C ⇔ C |
| ¬ | ¬ | ⋅ | 2 (P=⊥) | ¬P⊕¬C ⇔ ¬⊥⊕¬C ⇔ ⊤⊕¬C ⇔ ¬¬C ⇔ C |
| ⋅ | ⋅ | ¬ | 1 (P=⊤) | ¬(P⊕C) ⇔ ¬(⊤⊕C) ⇔ ¬¬C ⇔ C |
| ¬ | ⋅ | ¬ | 2 (P=⊥) | ¬(¬P⊕C) ⇔ ¬(¬⊥⊕C) ⇔ ¬(⊤⊕C) ⇔ ¬¬C ⇔ C |
| ⋅ | ¬ | ¬ | 2 (P=⊥) | ¬(P⊕¬C) ⇔ ¬(⊥⊕¬C) ⇔ ¬¬C ⇔ C |
| ¬ | ¬ | ¬ | 3 (P=⊤) | ¬(¬P⊕¬C) ⇔ ¬(¬⊤⊕¬C) ⇔ ¬(⊥⊕¬C) ⇔ ¬¬C ⇔ C |

Comment: This is a neat answer, but I'm having trouble seeing how the receiver can infer whether P is true or false, in order to evaluate the resulting compound statement in terms of C. If it's based on counting the negation flag (e.g. "It is not true that..."), I'm thinking specifically of cases where C's syntax includes the negation flag (e.g. C = "It is not true that someone else is more beautiful than you."). +1 though and hopefully I've just failed to wrap my head around it!

Comment: +1 - This was initially the intended answer, until I realized that the listener is not able to determine whether a statement is inverted. Then, f(c) = c becomes indistinguishable from f(~c) = ~c for function of the compliment, and you cannot ensure the compliment gets across clearly in a single statement. Please see my latest comment under the question for details as to why this question should be closed.

Answer (score 3):

Solve it by social convention:

> If your statement gets inverted, repeat it *once*! If you get your original meaning across the first time, don't repeat it. So if someone says the same thing twice in a row (with the second time possibly being an inversion of the first), you know that their intention was the opposite of whatever they said the first time.

Comment: What if you wax poetic... and then you forget the words when you have to repeat it a second time? And both your (slightly different) compliments become inverted? Then it becomes a double insult! There is a way to frame a compliment so you never have to repeat yourself and it will always get across clearly. +1 since it works assuming perfect memory, though :)

Comment: @Avi I'd suggest if your poetic statement gets inverted you say "oops, that was inverted" once or twice.

Comment: Good idea, but runs into a problem in the following scenario. You're on your deathbed with two statements left. You say "I hate you. That was not inverted." and before you say the last "Oops, that was inverted", you die. Your loved ones are left with the impression that you hated them...

Comment: @Avi ...and that's more likely than someone dying midway through a more complex statement? Consider me unconvinced.

Answer (score 2):

Easy.

> If your prior sentence was inverted, grunt. If someone is not sure if it was inverted, they can scream, requesting confirmation. If it was intentional, you can repeat it. Else, grunt.

Answer (score 0):

You could speak using a third person perspective, e.g. "Someone told me you look great today."

A negative to the statement would be that no one told you anything, so the compliment is coming from you, whereas a truth would still be taken as a compliment.

Comment: "Note that sub-statements when trying to say complex statements ... may also be inverted" - that probably means it could come out as "Someone told me you don't look great today".

Comment: Rob Watts' observation is correct. This won't work for the specified reason.

Answer (score 0):

**You could say something similar to:**

> "You look good or you look good or you look good." This creates a statement to the effect of "You look good || You look good || You look good." As only one of these three sub-statements can be inverted, the implications of the statement will always be positive.

Comment: The whole statement could be inverted, and/or any of the sub-statements. Either way, it is totally possible for the implication of the statement to be negative. This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If by "come across clearly", you mean "can be inferred", there can be a social convention of including a hash with each statement.

Answer (score 0):

Easier

> If your sentence was inverted, repeat the inverted part(s). Otherwise say the sentence, “did I stutter?” (or “did I not stutter?”).

> Any number of similar schemes could be come up with where the confirmation signal is a separate phrase and the amendment phrase can be made particular to the inverted subexpressions

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

> "It's true that you look lovely today"

If this gets inverted, the meaning stays the same:

> "It's not true that you look ugly today."

Which, while a bit confusing, syntactically, still gets the meaning across fairly well.